# How did some Jain Bunts became administrators of Hindu Temples?

Tags: temple, jainism

From this Wikipedia [Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_Bunt),

> Some Jain Bunts are hereditary trustees abd administrators of Hindu
>   Temples, an example being at the Dharamsthala Temple

How and why did Jain Bunts became the trustees and administrators of Hindu Temples?

.